# Doctrine OneToOne Bi- and Unidirectional with ZF2 Fieldsets not saving/hydrating

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2

I have 2 Doctrine entities (`Environment` and `EnvironmentConfig`). They have a [bi-directional OneToOne](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html#one-to-one-bidirectional)  relationship.

Each entity has their own Fieldset so that re-use is easy.

To create an `Environment` it can also have an `EnvironmentConfig`, however not required. To allow them to be made at the same time I have an `EnvironmentForm` that uses the `EnvironmentFieldset` and the `EnvironmentConfigFieldset`.

The Form renders properly. However, it saves the `Environment` but not the `EnvironmentConfig`.

Where is it that I've gone wrong in setting this up and how to fix it?

Code below, leaving out getters/setters, would be too much.

**Entities**

```
// abstract class AbstractEntity has $id + getters/setters.

class Environment extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var EnvironmentConfig
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Environment\Entity\EnvironmentConfig", inversedBy="environment")
     */
    protected $config;

    /**
     * @var EnvironmentScript
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="EnvironmentScript")
     */
    protected $script;

    //Getters/setters
}

class EnvironmentConfig extends AbstractEntity
{
    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255, nullable=false)
     */
    protected $name;

    /**
     * @var Environment
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Environment\Entity\Environment", mappedBy="config")
     */
    protected $environment;

    //Getters/setters
}
```

**Fieldsets**

```
class EnvironmentFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function init()
    {
        //Loads id element validation
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => Text::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => _('Name'),
                'label_attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'col-xs-2 col-form-label',
                ],
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'name',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'environment_config',
            'type' => EnvironmentConfigFieldset::class,
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => false,
            ],
        ]);

        $this->add([
            'type' => ObjectSelect::class,
            'name' => 'environment_script',
            'options' => [
                'object_manager' => $this->getEntityManager(),
                'target_class'   => EnvironmentScript::class,
                'property'       => 'id',
                'display_empty_item' => true,
                'empty_item_label'   => '---',
                'label_generator' => function ($targetEntity) {
                    return $targetEntity->getId() . ' - ' . $targetEntity->getName();
                },
            ],
        ]);
    }
}

class EnvironmentConfigFieldset extends AbstractFieldset
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function init()
    {
        //Loads id element validation
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'name',
            'type' => Text::class,
            'options' => [
                'label' => _('Name'),
                'label_attributes' => [
                    'class' => 'col-xs-2 col-form-label',
                ],
            ],
            'attributes' => [
                'id' => 'name',
                'class' => 'form-control'
            ],
        ]);

    }
}
```

**Form**

```
class EnvironmentForm extends AbstractForm
{
    /**
     * EnvironmentForm constructor.
     * @param null $name
     * @param array $options
     */
    public function __construct($name = null, array $options)
    {
        //Also adds CSRF
        parent::__construct($name, $options);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function init()
    {
        //Call parent initializer. Adds submit button.
        parent::init();

        $this->add([
            'name' => 'environment',
            'type' => EnvironmentFieldset::class,
            'options' => [
                'use_as_base_fieldset' => true,
            ],
        ]);
    }
}
```

**Edit: added debug data and `AddAction()`**
[image: Debug of form and request data]

Above debugging done on the `persist()` line in the function below.

```
public function addAction($formName, array $formOptions = null, $route, array $routeParams = [])
{
    if (!$this->formElementManager instanceof FormElementManagerV2Polyfill) {

        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Dependency FormElementManagerV2Polyfill not set. Please check Factory for this function.');
    }

    if (!class_exists($formName)) {

        throw new ClassNotFoundException('Given class could not be found. Does it exist?');
    }

    /** @var AbstractForm $form */
    $form = $this->getFormElementManager()->get($formName, (is_null($formOptions) ? [] : $formOptions));

    /** @var Request $request */
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->isPost()) {
        $form->setData($request->getPost());

        if ($form->isValid()) {
            $entity = $form->getObject();

            $this->getEntityService()->getEntityManager()->persist($entity);
            $this->getEntityService()->getEntityManager()->flush();

            $this->flashMessenger()->addSuccessMessage(
                _('Successfully created object.')
            );

            $this->redirectToRoute($route, $this->getRouteParams($entity, $routeParams));
        }
    }

    return [
        'form' => $form,
        'validationMessages' => $form->getMessages() ?: '',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created a field called `'environment_config'` but in class `Environment` you called `protected $config;`. Both names must be the same. Same problem for `'environment_script'` field and `$script` attribute.

Another thing, you want to create a `EnvironmentConfig` dynamically so you must add in `$config` annotation a `cascade` option to be able to create a `$config` from `Environment`:

```
/**
 * @var EnvironmentConfig
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Environment\Entity\EnvironmentConfig", inversedBy="environment", cascade={"persist"})
 */
protected $config;
```

Comment: Ah super thanks! Worst thing about that answer is: I used to always do that so it was never a problem, something I did automatically and had forgotten about. Thanks for the reminder, now stomping myself for forgetting basics of Doctrine :( ;)